# Upload an image to Amazon S3 API with Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am making an app which will access a phones camera from the browser.  Allow the user to take a picture and then save the picture to a Amazon S3 bucket.  I am having trouble making a successful API post.  The error message that comes back is just a copy of the very long Body that I am sending.

Here is my server side code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../modules/pool');
const router = express.Router();
const { rejectUnauthenticated } = require('../modules/authentication-middleware');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3();

aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'Access_KeyID',
    secretAccessKey: 'Access_Key',
    region: 'us-east-2',
});

//POST request to Amazon API
router.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    let pic = req.body.picture[0]
    console.log(pic)
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'beerphoto',
        Key: req.body.filename,
        Body : fs.createReadStream(pic),
        ContentType: 'image/png',
        Expires: 60,
    }
    s3.upload(params, function(err,data){
        if(err) {
            console.log('err')
        }
        if (data) {
            console.log("Uploaded in:", data.Location);
          }
    })

})

module.exports = router;
```

I am wondering if the issue is with the picture data.  Here is what is being passed into the Body,

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASQA"
```

The actual string is much, much, longer (around 26,000 characters). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fs.createReadStream()` is not your option. This method creates a stream for data from local file system. However, you already have your picture in RAM, you even have a reference for it with `req.body.picture[0]`. I think there's no need to leverage streams at all, just use your base64 string, or maybe convert to Buffer instance, according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property).

Also, you mentioned that your pictures in base64 are at around 26000 characters, which is at least 52 kbs in UTF-8. Imagine a high load for your server with 1000 request with large pictures, your process might run out of memory, because pictures are just too big to fit in it. To avoid that you can let your clients (not server) to upload to S3 directly and securely (without exposing secret keys) with [signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property).

Comment: I’m now getting an access denied issue. Your solution of just removing the fs.createReadStream() seems to have solved my initial problem.